# Showing that $x= y$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $x,y,a,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with the Euclidean norm such that $||x-a||=||y-a||$ and $||x-b||=||y-b||$. Is it true that $x= y$? Intuitively this is true to me, but I'm not too sure how to show that. Is there any suggestion or hint?

Comment: For $n=1$ and  $a=b=0$ , we have $|x|=|y| \not\Rightarrow x=y$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** If $n=2$, your question is whether or not the intersection of two circles always consists of a single point.

Answer (score 2):

This is false even in two dimensions: set $a=(0,1),b=(0,-2),x=(1,0),y=(-1,0)$.